# JPA orderBy annonation help required

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying a similar query with annotation and order by is not showing in the output sql; any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
Select * from Parent p, Child c, GrandChild gc WHERE id=? and 
p.id=c.parentID and c.code = gc.code order by gc.code,gc.seqNum
```

Here's my Java class:

```
Public class Parent {
    int id;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "parent")
    @NotEmpty
    List<Child> listChidrean;
} 

Public class Child{
    int parentID;
    String code;
    String childName;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "Code", referencedColumnName = "Code")
    @OrderBy("code,seqNum")
    GrandChild grandChild;
 }


Public class GrandChild {
    String code;
    String childName;
    int seqNum;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`@OrderBy` is for multi-valued properties, i.e. it is used for lists. It then specifies the order in that list. It's not used for single-valued properties such as *GrandChild*.

Answer (score 0):

`OrderBy` definition as per the doc says

Specifies the ordering of the elements of a collection valued association or element collection at the point when the association or collection is `retrieved`.

that means for your example, you should have a list of grandchild then only orderby applies like below

```
Parent parent = manager.find(Parent.class, id);
List<GrandChild> grandChildren = parent.listChidren[0].grandChild;
```

so here parent will not be having sorted values because `OrderBy` applies only at the retrival side so only grandChildren is sorted list provided grandchild must be a list rather than single object.